# Get array difference between multiple arrays of different sizes

Tags: javascript, lodash, underscore.js, ramda.js

Been going around in circles with this for a while.

For example let's say I have different times slots stored as this

```
let timechunks1 = [["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"], ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"], ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"]] 
let timechunks2 = [["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"], ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"], ["09:00", "10:00"]]


 for (let i=0; i< timechunks.length; i++) {
 differences.push(_.difference(timechunks[0], timechunks[i]))      
}
```

Would need to extract 12:00 since it doesn't appear in others. Closest I got was with underscore _difference but alas it's not doing what I expected.

For timechunks1 I'm looking to return "12:00"
For timechunks2 I'm looking for a way to return "11:00"

Added another example

```
[
["09:00", "10:00", "11:00" ,"13:00"],
["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "13:00"], 
["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"]
]
```

for which it would return ["13:00", "12:00"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build this on implementations of `intersection`, `difference`, and `uniq`.  Here's how I might do it with Ramda's versions:

```js
const notCommon = (xs, common = xs .reduce (intersection)) => 
  uniq (xs .flatMap (x => difference (x, common)))


const timechunks1 = [["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"], ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"], ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"]] 
const timechunks2 = [["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"], ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"], ["09:00", "10:00"]]
const timechunks3 = [["09:00", "10:00", "11:00" ,"13:00"], ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "13:00"], ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"]]

console .log (notCommon (timechunks1))
console .log (notCommon (timechunks2))
console .log (notCommon (timechunks3))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {intersection, uniq, difference} = R                  </script>
```

We find the elements in common to all the sets by using `intersection`  Here we `reduce` over Ramda's binary version.  Other versions might let you do something like `common = intersection (xs)` or `common = intersection (...xs)`, depending on their exact API.  Then we `flatMap` a `difference` function over the timechunks, returning the values not found in `common`.  And finally we take only the uniq elements of that list.

Comment: Thanks ! Quite powerful data manipulation will look more into ramda! This covers all edge cases. I will implement this right away. In the meanwhile I had looked at the problem the other way around and only return duplicates that appear less times than the timechunks array length which I knew beforehand represents the timeslots for each available agent.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is equivalent to my answer.

Comment: @Julian: yes it is.  Interesting, I've never thought about symmetric difference extending beyond two inputs.

Answer (score 2):

In set-theoretic terms, what you are looking for is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference). You can find this set by taking the union and subtracting the intersection:

```
function symmetricDifference(...sets) {
    return _.difference(_.union(...sets), _.intersection(...sets));
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Learned something new :) Seeing the venn diagrams helps visualize it better ) If I knew how it's called would have found that Lodash even has a function that does this called _.xor() but doesn't go all the way https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#xor

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't go all the way"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an immutable way of doing it

```
function findTimeSlot(timechunks){
    const slots = _.map(_.zip(...timechunks), _.compact);
    const maxChunk = _.max(_.map(slots, slot => slot.length));

    return _.unique(_.find(slots, (slot) => slot.length < maxChunk));
}
```

returns

> `["11:00"]` for `findTimeSlot(timechunks2)`

And

> `["12:00"]` for `findTimeSlot(timechunks1)`

Let know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findUniqueTimeSlots(timechunks) {
  const hm = {};
  timechunks.flat(1).forEach(el => {
    if (hm.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
      hm[el] += 1;
    } else {
      hm[el] = 1;
    }
  });
  return Object.keys(hm).filter(key => hm[key] === 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by following these steps:

- find the common timechunk, `_.intersection(...timechunks)`
- iterate the timechunks and find the difference of each from the common, `_.difference(timechunk, commons)`

Below snippet could help you

```js
const timechunks1 = [
  ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"],
  ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"],
  ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"],
]
const timechunks2 = [
  ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"],
  ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00"],
  ["09:00", "10:00"],
]
const timechunks3 = [
  ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "13:00"],
  ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "13:00"],
  ["09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"],
]

const getDifferences = (timechunks) =>
  _.chain(timechunks)
    .map((timechunk) => _.difference(timechunk, _.intersection(...timechunks)))
    .flatten()
    .uniq()
    .value()

console.log(getDifferences(timechunks1))
console.log(getDifferences(timechunks2))
console.log(getDifferences(timechunks3))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that you call `intersection` repeatedly on the same values.