# Find deep difference between nested array of object with lodash or underscore or vanilla js

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, underscore.js

**Deeply Nested Objects I want to compare**

```
const prevObj = {
    "ui_data": [
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "editable": true,
                    "id": "22615650-510a-11ec-8393-cfd004935be3",
                    "mandatory": false,
                    "modifiable": true,
                    "options": [],
                    "t_id": "text",
                    "title": "Text 1",
                    "type": "FormFieldType.textField"
                },
                {
                    "editable": true,
                    "id": "2a6f9000-510a-11ec-8393-cfd004935be3",
                    "mandatory": false,
                    "modifiable": true,
                    "options": [],
                    "t_id": "cb",
                    "title": "Check Box 2",
                    "type": "FormFieldType.checkBox"
                }
            ],
            "id": "fe8223e0-5109-11ec-8393-cfd004935be3",
            "title": "Page-1",
            "type": "FormContainerType.page"
        }
    ]
}

const newObj = {
    "ui_data": [
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "editable": true,
                    "id": "22615650-510a-11ec-8393-cfd004935be3",
                    "mandatory": false,
                    "modifiable": true,
                    "options": [],
                    "t_id": "text",
                    "title": "Text 1",
                    "type": "FormFieldType.textField"
                },
                {
                    "editable": true,
                    "id": "2a6f9000-510a-11ec-8393-cfd004935be3",
                    "mandatory": false,
                    "modifiable": true,
                    "options": [],
                    "t_id": "cb",
                    "title": "Check Box 2",
                    "type": "FormFieldType.checkBox"
                }
            ],
            "id": "fe8223e0-5109-11ec-8393-cfd004935be3",
            "title": "Page-1",
            "type": "FormContainerType.page"
        }
    ]
}

const wrapAddedKey = newValue => ({ oldValue: undefined, newValue });
function changes(oldCollection, newCollection) {
    const diff = _.reduce(oldCollection, function (result, oldValue, key) {
        const newValue = newCollection[key];
        if (_.isObject(oldValue) && _.isObject(newValue)) {
            const diff = _.compact(changes(oldValue, newValue));
            if (!_.isEmpty(diff)) {
                result[key] = diff;
            };
        } else if (oldValue !== newValue) {
            result[key] = { oldValue: oldValue, newValue: newValue };
        }
        return result;
    }, _.isArray(oldCollection) ? [] : {});
    const addedKeys = _.difference(_.keys(newCollection), _.keys(oldCollection));
    const additions = _.pick(newCollection, _.compact(addedKeys));
    return _.extend(diff, __.mapObject(additions, wrapAddedKey));
}
```

I am creating an algorithm to compare deeply nested objects, I am using lodash to compare changes in object. I have two deeply nested objects which also contains arrays inside them. I want to compare to see if anything is updated, created or deleted inside them. Above code is working for one level deep array but in case if there is an array of objects is inside array of objects this code do not works. I have shared the example of objects above. Output that I am expecting with full like if something new is created then it should return following.

```
{
oldValues : null,
newValues : {
    // Values of newly created items
}
}
```

If something is deleted then it should return

```
{
    oldValues  : {
         // Older Values of deleted item
    },
    newValues : null
}
```

If something is updated then it should return

```
{
     oldValues  : {
        // Older Values of item
    },
    newValues : {
        // Newer Values of item
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparing difference between Objects can be tricky, have you looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/just-diff

Comment: use _.isEqual() function
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual

Comment: JSON Diff, plenty of scripts out there

Comment: Your newest `prevObj` and `newObj` are identical. This is the reason why you're getting an empty object. If you make them different, you'll find that the original code from my answer already works to arbitrary depth because it is recursive. The only things that seems lacking in my answer, is that it is using `undefined` instead of `null` to indicate missing values. I'll address that.

Comment: By the way, it would be nice to acknowledge that you copied and then edited the code from my answer. Even better would be to also include your original code, because my answer is responding to that code. Your edits made the code worse; those two calls to `_.compact` shouldn't be there (they lead to information loss) and you duplicated the `_` in `_.mapObject` on the penultimate line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Understanding the problem

The example objects in the question use an invalid notation and also assign a global variable `anotherArr` as a side effect, which was probably unintended. (*Update: the example objects in the question were changed after I posted this answer. The objects below still resemble the original example objects.*) In this answer, I will assume the following notation instead:

```js
const prevObj = {
    arr: [{
        name: 'Ankur',
    }, {
        email: 'ankur4736@gmail.com',
    }, {
        key: 456,
    }, [{
        name: 'Shubham',
        anotherNestedArr: [{
            name: 'Gundeep Paji'
        }],
    }]],
};

const newObj = {
    arr: [{
        name: 'Shubham',
    }, {
        email: 'shubham@gmail.com',
    }, {
        key: 466,
    }, [{
        name: 'Gundeep Paji',
        anotherNestedArr: [{
            name: 'Ankur'
        }],
    }]],
};
```

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you not only want to perform a deep comparison between the objects, but also create a new object that contains a description of the differences. You state that your current code works for objects but not for arrays. From your code, I'm gathering that you want to the diff to look like this:

```js
const diff = {
    arr: [{
        name: {
            oldValue: 'Ankur',
            newValue: 'Shubham',
        },
    }, {
        email: {
            oldValue: 'ankur4736@gmail.com',
            newValue: 'shubham@gmail.com',
        },
    }, {
        key: {
            oldValue: 456,
            newValue: 466,
        },
    }, [{
        name: {
            oldValue: 'Shubham',
            newValue: 'Gundeep Paji',
        },
        anotherNestedArr: [{
            name: {
                oldValue: 'Gundeep Paji',
                newValue: 'Ankur',
            },
        }],
    }]],
};
```

### Sparse vs. dense arrays

Before we commence, I should point out that there are two different ways one may create a new array containing only the values from the old array that have changed in the new array. For simplicity, I will use two arrays of numbers as an example:

```js
const oldArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const newArr = [1, 1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 7];
// differences:    ^        ^
```

For the sake of illustration, assume for a moment that we only store the old values in the diff, instead of `{oldValue, newValue}` objects. Our diff array will start out empty either way, but if we choose the *dense* way of representing the diff, we simply append every element of `oldArr` that has changed in `newArr` to the end:

```js
const denseDiff = [2, 5];
```

The advantage of this representation is that `denseDiff.length` will tell us a straightforward truth, i.e., two elements have changed. The disadvantage is that we have no way to tell what was the original index of the changed elements.

The *sparse* way is more complicated:

```js
const sparseDiff = [, 2, , , 5];
```

`sparseDiff.length`, which is `5`, no longer tells us the number of changed elements. Instead, it only conveys the highest index of a changed element. In addition, if we take an index between `0` and `sparseDiff.length` that didn't change, for example `sparseDiff[3]`, it will always tell us `undefined`, of which the meaning is not clear.

There is a lot of room for confusion here, which generally isn't a good thing in programming. However, the sparse way has the major advantage that the indices of changed elements are always equal between `oldArr` and `sparseDiff`. That is, we maintain the following invariant for every index `i`:

```js
oldArr[i] == newArr[i] ? sparseDiff[i] == undefined : sparseDiff[i] == oldArr[i]
```

Fortunately, there is also a way for us to find directly which indices correspond to the changed elements. `_.keys` (or `Object.keys`) will tell us the indices of just the elements that were set explicitly (because they changed):

```js
_.keys(sparseDiff)  // ['1', '4']
```

`_.keys(sparseDiff).length` will even tell us the number of elements that changed. We can get all the information we could obtain with the dense representation, just in a more roundabout and confusing way.

Concluding, sparse arrays are arguably the correct approach here, because they allow us to obtain all the information we might need. I pointed out the disadvantages of sparse arrays anyway, to hightlight that there is still a tradeoff.

### Your code

Before jumping to solutions, let's take this opportunity to learn as much as possible. There are a couple of things in your code that stood out to me.

#### Double outer function

This is the first thing I noticed:

```js
function difference(oldValues, newValues) {
    function changes(oldValues, newValues) {
        //...
    }

    return changes(oldValues, newValues);
}
```

The `difference` function is simply forwarding its arguments in the same order to `changes` and then echoing its return value. That means that `difference` isn't really doing anything. You could remove the outermost `difference` function, call `changes` instead of `difference` and still get the same result:

```js
function changes(oldValues, newValues) {
    //...
}
```

#### _.transform

The second thing I noticed is that you're using `_.transform`. If we look at how this function was conceived, it turns out to be a variant of `_.reduce` that can stop iteration early by returning `false` from the iteratee. Since the iteratee must be able to return `false` but we must also be able to obtain a result at the end, this means that the iteratee must modify the accumulator in place, instead of returning it as we would do in `_.reduce`. There are two major problems with this.

Firstly, modifying in place doesn't work with immutable values such as strings. For this reason, `_transform` only works on objects and arrays. Consider the following function to reverse a string, which can work with `_.reduce` but not with `_.transform`:

```js
function reverse(string) {
    return _.reduce(string, (result, char) => char + result);
}
```

You *could* work around this by wrapping the `result` in an object and then unwrapping it afterwards, but this means you're working around the limitations of `_.transform` while you should be using `_.reduce` in the first place.

Secondly and more importantly, *partially transforming an object makes no sense*. The keys of an object are unordered. Suppose that during iteration, you find the stop condition on a particular key. By pure coincidence, some of the other keys have already been visited while others haven't yet. There is no defensible reason why the keys that have already been visited should be part of your transformed result and the other keys shouldn't, since this division is completely arbitrary.

`_.transform` is useless for immutable values and meaningless for unordered collections. How about ordered collections, arrays? At first sight, there are some reasonable scenarios where you might want to partially transform an array. For example, to compute the least number above a threshold that can be obtained by summing numbers in an array from the start:

```js
function thresholdPartialSum(numbers, threshold) {
    return _.transform(numbers, function(result, number) {
        result.wrapped += number;
        return result.wrapped <= threshold;
    }, { wrapped: 0 }).wrapped;
}
```

Note the `wrapped` appearing in four places. We are working around `_.transform`'s limitation of having to modify the accumulator in place here, too.

Admittedly, `_.transform` has a performance advantage over `_.reduce` in this case. However, we need *neither*. Partially iterating arrays is already handled perfectly well by good old `_.find` and similar functions. Moreover, since we have to modify the accumulator in place anyway, we might as well close over it. `_.find` will handle scenarios like these just as well as `_.transform`, with less complexity:

```js
function thresholdPartialSum(numbers, threshold) {
    let partialSum = 0;
    find(numbers, function(number) {
        partialSum += number;
        return partialSum > threshold;
    });
    return partialSum;
}
```

In conclusion, you should *never* use `_.transform`. Use `_.reduce` or `_.find` instead.

#### Duplicate recursion

This is the third thing I noticed:

```js
if (!_.isEqual(value, oldValues[key])) {
    // recursion here
}
```

While this will not lead to incorrect results, `_.isEqual` is itself recursive. It bases its return value on whether any difference is found. This means that when a difference is found, you end up recursively iterating both values again, just to find back the difference that `_.isEqual` already identified but didn't tell you the position of.

At first glance, this may seem not so problematic. You might recurse twice instead of once. Not the most efficient possible, but at most twice as slow, right? Unfortunately, the duplication doesn't stop here. Once you recursively call your own `changes` function, `_.isEqual` will be invoked again for each subelement of the element you recursed into, and it will be recursive *again*.

To quantify this, let's start by visualizing a nested object as a tree.

```js
const tree = {
    mainBranch1: {
        branch1_1: {
            twig1_1_1: {
                leaf1_1_1_1: 'value 1.1.1.1',
                leaf1_1_1_2: 'value 1.1.1.2',
            },
            twig1_1_2: {
                leaf1_1_2_1: 'value 1.1.2.1',
                leaf1_1_2_2: 'value 1.1.2.2',
            },
        },
        branch1_2: {
            twig1_2_1: {
                leaf1_2_1_1: 'value 1.2.1.1',
                leaf1_2_1_2: 'value 1.2.1.2',
            },
            twig1_2_2: {
                leaf1_2_2_1: 'value 1.2.2.1',
                leaf1_2_2_2: 'value 1.2.2.2',
            },
        },
    },
    mainBranch2: {
        branch2_1: {
            twig2_1_1: {
                leaf2_1_1_1: 'value 2.1.1.1',
                leaf2_1_1_2: 'value 2.1.1.2',
            },
            twig2_1_2: {
                leaf2_1_2_1: 'value 2.1.2.1',
                leaf2_1_2_2: 'value 2.1.2.2',
            },
        },
        branch2_2: {
            twig2_2_1: {
                leaf2_2_1_1: 'value 2.2.1.1',
                leaf2_2_1_2: 'value 2.2.1.2',
            },
            twig2_2_2: {
                leaf2_2_2_1: 'value 2.2.2.1',
                leaf2_2_2_2: 'value 2.2.2.2',
            },
        },
    },
};
```

We have a tree with four levels of branching (not including `tree` itself). There are sixteen leafs.

Recursion will stop at the `leaf` keys, so let's count how many times `_.isEqual` will visit a leaf key. Assume that we will be comparing `tree` to another object with a similar structure and about half of the leaf values has changed.

First, we call `changes` on `tree` and the other object. We invoke `_.isEqual` once for each `mainBranch`. `_.isEqual` recursively calls itself until it reaches the leaf keys. It needs to visit about half of the leafs in order to find a difference, at which point it knows it must return `false`. At this point, we have visited each leaf half a time on average.

Every time `_.isEqual` returns `false`, we recursively call `changes` on the corresponding main branch. Each call to `changes` then invokes `_.isEqual` once for each `branch` within. `_.isEqual` recursively calls itself again until it reaches the leaf keys. Now we have visited each leaf once on average.

`_.isEqual` again returns `false` every time, so we recurse into `changes` again. The whole pattern repeats and we're at one and a half visits per leaf.

We finally repeat the whole pattern one more time with the `twig`s and we end up at two invocations of `_.isEqual` per leaf key on average. That means `16 * 2 = 32` invocations of `_.isEqual` on a leaf key in total. The total number of invocations per leaf is equal to the depth of the tree times the number of leafs, divided by two. In complexity analysis, we call this log-linear or quasilinear [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).

This is the worst case. With fewer than half of the leafs differing, `changes` will recurse less often, while with more than half of the leafs differing, `_.isEqual` will stop its own recursion sooner. Nevertheless, without the duplicate recursion, we would need to visit each leaf only once, regardless of the depth of the tree. After all, when we determine whether a key has changed, we might as well directly record the difference. With large, deeply nested structures this can be a big difference, especially if it happens in a hot loop.

Removing the duplication requires that we change the algorithm from a pre-order traversal to a post-order [traversal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/). That is, instead of first determining whether there are any differences with a larger branch and then finding those differences within each of its smaller branches, we have to go straight to collecting all the differences within the smallest branches. If we find any differences within a smaller branch, we then know that we should also record the containing larger branch.

### Solution

Enough theory. The following code addresses the issues I discussed above and works for objects as well as arrays. It works regardless of whether you're using Underscore or Lodash.

```js
function changes(oldCollection, newCollection) {
    return _.reduce(oldCollection, function(result, oldValue, key) {
        const newValue = newCollection[key];
        if (_.isObject(oldValue) && _.isObject(newValue)) {
            const diff = changes(oldValue, newValue);
            if (!_.isEmpty(diff)) result[key] = diff;
        } else if (oldValue !== newValue) {
            result[key] = { oldValue, newValue };
        }
        return result;
    }, _.isArray(oldCollection) ? [] : {});
}
```

### Final remarks

As in the original question, the diff object returned by `changes` contains a nested `{oldValue, newValue}` object for each changed leaf key. This could lead to ambiguities if either the old or the new object contains keys with the name `oldValue` or `newValue`. This is not as crazy as it may seem; consider comparing diffs at two different points in time.

To avoid such situations, you could opt to store only the old value (or only the new value) in the diff. Since you'll know the exact location of the value that changed, it will be trivial to look up the corresponding key in the other object. You need to change only one line to make the algorithm behave this way, but this is left as an exercise to the reader.

Also as in the original question, the above solution does not take into account that the new collection might have new keys that didn't exist in the old collection. If you want to detect new keys and you can accept that deleted keys will be missed, simply iterate over `newCollection` instead of over `oldCollection`. If you want to pick up missing keys on both sides, determine the common keys and the uncommon keys by the [symmetric difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63197364/1166087) first. Treat the common keys as above while recording the uncommon keys directly as differences. This is, again, left as an exercise to the reader.

### Update: detecting both deleted and added elements

In the "final remarks" above, I commented that my solution above, like in the original question, did not detect newly added elements in objects and arrays. Ankur Sharma commented that this was actually one of the problems he was seeking a solution for in his question. To address this, below is a new version of my solution.

*The code below assumes Underscore. For Lodash 4, use `_.mapValues` instead of `_.mapObject`.*

```js
// Helper for the call to _.mapObject/_.mapValues below.
const wrapAddedKey = newValue => ({ oldValue: undefined, newValue });

function changes(oldCollection, newCollection) {
    const diff = _.reduce(oldCollection, function(result, oldValue, key) {
        const newValue = newCollection[key];
        if (_.isObject(oldValue) && _.isObject(newValue)) {
            const diff = changes(oldValue, newValue);
            if (!_.isEmpty(diff)) result[key] = diff;
        } else if (oldValue !== newValue) {
            result[key] = { oldValue, newValue };
        }
        return result;
    }, _.isArray(oldCollection) ? [] : {});
    const addedKeys = _.difference(_.keys(newCollection), _.keys(oldCollection));
    const additions = _.pick(newCollection, addedKeys);
    return _.extend(diff, _.mapObject(additions, wrapAddedKey));
}
```

### Update 2

From another update to the question, it became clear that the asker wanted to represent missing values as `null` instead of as `undefined`. The following code addresses this.

```js
// Helper for the call to _.mapObject/_.mapValues below.
const wrapAddedKey = newValue => ({ oldValue: null, newValue });

function changes(oldCollection, newCollection) {
    const diff = _.reduce(oldCollection, function(result, oldValue, key) {
        const newValue = key in newCollection ? newCollection[key] : null;
        if (_.isObject(oldValue) && _.isObject(newValue)) {
            const diff = changes(oldValue, newValue);
            if (!_.isEmpty(diff)) result[key] = diff;
        } else if (oldValue !== newValue) {
            result[key] = { oldValue, newValue };
        }
        return result;
    }, _.isArray(oldCollection) ? [] : {});
    const addedKeys = _.difference(_.keys(newCollection), _.keys(oldCollection));
    const additions = _.pick(newCollection, addedKeys);
    return _.extend(diff, _.mapObject(additions, wrapAddedKey));
}
```

Comment: This solution is not working in case any new object has been added to the array. I am creating audit trails for my data. In case data is updated i am getting older and newer object which I am comparing to see if anything is created. Please help me solving this. I am banging my head.

Comment: Alright, I'll update the answer later today.

Comment: I have updated object in the questions, I want to detect if anything new created, updated or deleted in object and return old values and new values

Comment: @AnkurSharma I added a new section at the bottom of my answer that addresses newly added elements.

Comment: Such a life saver you are. God bless you!

Comment: Glad I could help you. If you feel that the answer fully addresses your question, please mark it as accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Just one more case needs to be handled in above question, I have updated the question entirely. Please have a look.

Comment: Don't replace your entire question by an entire different question after someone already answered it. That makes your question a moving target. I have added an update to represent missing values as `null` instead of `undefined`. This is the final version of my answer. See also my comments to your question.